# Migrate data from localStorage to chrome.storage in a chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome app written in the older version, and I'm updating it now.

I'm wondering how I can migrate the data in the update, since 'localStorage' isn't accessible at all. How can I prevent data loss? Does chrome automatically moves the key/values from 'localStorage' to 'chrome.storage'?

Comment: you can see localStorage data from chrome inspector (ctrl + shift+ i ). I think you have to manually migrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very interesting question.

So, you're migrating a "legacy" app to the new Chrome Apps platform? I'm assuming you can no longer upload a legacy app update, only a new app update?

In that case, I'm afraid you stand to completely lose the data. `localStorage` is no longer available from any context of your app, and no, it will not be automatically migrated.

---

> Updated 04/09/2015: The legacy packaged app deprecation schedule has been revised. In August, all existing legacy packaged app listings will be removed from the Chrome Web Store’s search and browse functions. Existing legacy packaged apps can be updated until Chrome stops loading them in February of 2016.

If the Web Store **still** accepts updates to legacy apps, you will need to make a migration step yourself. I'm not sure `chrome.storage` is available in legacy apps (note that it requires the `"storage"` permission), but if it is, an intermediate version that performs the migration, for example:

```
var storage = {};
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  // You may need to deserialize the value
  storage[localStorage.key(i)] = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
}
chrome.storage.local.set(storage, function() { console.log("Migrated"); });
```

Upload such a version to the store, wait as long as you can for people to get it and migrate, then update to a proper app.

Some people who did not update in this timeframe will still lose their data, but there's nothing you can do *now*, after not migrating for 1.5 years that [legacy apps were deprecated](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/06/migrate-your-legacy-packaged-apps-to.html).

Comment: I think you can still update the legacy apps, so I'll just do an intermediary step where its saved for both 'localStorage' and 'chrome.storage' and then later on do the update to the recent app version. Thanks for the help!